# how to convert .yuv video to .y .u .v for each frame

Tags: video, yuv

I am trying to convert .yuv video into separate .y .u .v for each frame of a video.

```
suppose video has 60 frames then it should output total 180 files. 
.y for 1st frame   .u for 1st frame   .v for 1st frame
.y for 2nd frame   .u for 2nd frame   .v for 2nd frame
.
.
.
.y for 60th frame   .u for 60th frame   .v for 60th frame
```

can anyone suggest how to do this?

note : There are some softwares available but they give .y .u .v for entire video (only 3 files as a output videoname.y videoname.u videoname.v).

Comment: But how can I ensure that extracted bytes are valid y cb cr.  And also in extraction of y cb cr how should I extract? (means for y 1st 640x480 pixels for cb next 640x480/4 n for cr last 640x480/4 bytes or I need to extract in different way)

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#YCbCr)

> Y′CbCr is often confused with the YUV color space, and typically the
>   terms YCbCr and YUV are used interchangeably, leading to some
>   confusion; when referring to signals in video or digital form, the
>   term "YUV" mostly means "Y′CbCr".

Lets assume the video is in [YCbCr 4:2:0 8bpp plane-separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:2:0) format with a resolution of 640x480, then all you need to do is:

**For 1 frame**

```
To extract Y-component
Read 640*480 bytes

To extract Cb-component
Read 640*480/4 bytes

To extract Cr-component
Read 640*480/4 bytes
```

Repeat for all frames.

The size for 1 frame is `640*480*3/2=460800 bytes`

For *other* YCbCr formats, see http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php